# Why does Slurm kill one particular user's jobs after a few seconds?

Tags: slurm

I administer a Slurm cluster with many users and the operation of the cluster currently appears "totally normal" for all users; except for one.
This one user gets all attempts to run commands through Slurm killed after 20-25 seconds.
The following minimal example reproduces the error:

```
$ sudo -u <the_user> srun --pty sleep 25
srun: job 110962 queued and waiting for resources
srun: job 110962 has been allocated resources
srun: Force Terminated job 110962
srun: Job step aborted: Waiting up to 32 seconds for job step to finish.
slurmstepd: error: *** STEP 110962.0 ON <node> CANCELLED AT 2021-04-09T16:33:35 ***
srun: error: <node>: task 0: Terminated
```

When this happens, I find this line in the `slurmctld` log:

```
_slurm_rpc_kill_job: REQUEST_KILL_JOB JobId=110962 uid <the_users_uid>
```

It only happens for '<the_user>' and not for any other user that I know of. This very similar but shorter-running example works fine:

```
$ sudo -u <the_user> srun --pty sleep 20
srun: job 110963 queued and waiting for resources
srun: job 110963 has been allocated resources
```

Note that when I run `srun --pty sleep 20` as myself, `srun` does not output the two `srun: job...` lines. This seems to me to be an additional indication that `srun` is subject to some different settings for '<the_user>'.
All settings that I have been able to inspect appear identical for '<the_user>' as for other users. I have checked, and 'MaxWall' is *not* set for this user and not for any other user, either. Other users belonging to the same Slurm account do not experience this problem.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63776246/srun-used-in-a-loop-srun-job-step-aborted-waiting-up-to-32-seconds-for-job-st) sounds related, but I do not think the explanation seems to be the same.

What could be causing this?

**Update - the plot thickens**

When this unfortunate user's jobs get allocated, I see this message in '/var/log/slurm/slurmctld.log':

```
sched: _slurm_rpc_allocate_resources JobId=111855 NodeList=<node>
```

and shortly after, I see this message:

```
select/cons_tres: common_job_test: no job_resources info for JobId=110722_* rc=0
```

Job 110722_* is a pending array job by another user that is pending due to 'QOSMaxGRESPerUser'. One pending part of this array job (110722_57) eventually ends up taking over job 111855's CPU cores when 111855 gets killed. This leads me to believe that 110722_57 causes 111855 to be killed. However, 110722_57 remains pending afterwards.

Some of the things I fail to understand here are:

- Why would a pending job kill another job, yet remain pending afterwards?
- How would a pending job even have privileges to kill another job in the first place?
- Why would this only affect '<the_user>'s jobs but not those of other users?

None of this is intended to happen. I am guessing it must be caused by some settings specific to '<the_user>', but I cannot figure out what they are and they are not supposed to be like this. If these are settings we admins somehow caused, it was unintended.

**Update 2**

The problem has magically disappeared and can no longer be reproduced.

NB: some details have been anonymized as `<something>` above.

Comment: This problem has magically disappeared and I can no longer reproduce it.
The user tried running a Slurm job with the `-p` option (specifying our only partition 'batch'). We usually don't use `-p` since we have only one partition.
Since then we have been unable to reproduce the described problem. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem for days with various trials, and with `-p` option, the random killing problem is magically gone.

Thank you, Thomas Arildsen, for sharing your solution in the comment.

Comment: This probably should be a Community Wiki answer.